# Behat error: 'Undefined steps' when using valid rexeg (optional text/variable in gherkin)

Tags: php, regex, behat, gherkin

I have these two steps that I want to include in a single gherkin step.

```
When I search for **"existing product"** via **"lite search"**
When I search for **"existing product"** by **name** via **"advanced search"**
```

```
* @When I search for :searchObject(?: by :searchMethod)? via :searchSection
```

Basically I want to make "by :searchMethod" an optional part of the step.
PHPStorm and other regex testers show it as valid regex, even highlighting my variables. But when running it tells me it is an undefined step.

I could try (.*) but I don't want to include the word "by" into the variable. I also tried`I search for :searchObject(?: by)? (|:searchMethod )via :searchSection`.

Comment: Try `When I search for (.*?)(?: by \\w+)? via (.*)`

Comment: Same behavior as before. Undefined Step.